# Datagridview cell host usercontrol

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to include the following user control in this [link] (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a644fc/multicolumn-combobox-with-configurable-display-and-value-members-and-fast-search-functionality/) to my datagridview, but i dont where to start. I followed the msdn example but It doesn't work. Can someone show me how will i add the said control in the datagridview column? thanks.

Comment: You have to download the .zip file. Open the solution in Visual studio. Build the project. Then you add the .dll (located at the bin/debug folder) that was created to your project. And only then you can use that control.

Comment: thanks. I need to host it in datagridview just the like example in msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx?PHPSESSID=o1fb21liejulfgrptbmi9dec92)

Comment: Ok. I understood you had a problem even before, just by adding the dll. In that case, you have to show me the code you adapted by that sample at msdn. I hope you changed something there. That sample is about a Calendar column.

Comment: my problem using the code in the msdn is i dont know where will i put the usercontrol.